# OAuth2 without Login

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser, oauth-2.0

I would like to know is it's possible to do an authentication OAuth2 only with the CLIENT_ID and SECRET_KEY

The process would be the next:

1- Client registers on my website and I create theirs CLIENT_ID AND SECRET_KEY

2- Client enter to another website and then they have to able to generate the Access Token passing the CLIENT_ID and SECRET_KEY from the **Browser** using Javascript

Is it possible to do this?

TIA!

What I expect is an OAuth2 authentication without login page, just with the CLIENT and SECREY Key

Answer (score 1):

There is a oauth2 flow called `client_credentials` that uses a `client_id` and `client_secret`.

If your server supports then in theory it's possible to make a Javascript client that asks a user for these values and exchange them for an `access_token`.

Typically this isn't used for untrusted clients (like in a browser) but if you ask a user (presumably a developer) directly for these values I don't think there's a lot of harm. However, asking for a `client_id` and `client_secret` isn't all that different from asking for a username and password, so I hope you have a good reason to want this.

Comment: Hi Evert! Thanks for your answer, I have a doubt, Is really secure use this method? 
Because once time the webpage is loaded this data (client_id, client_secret) could be watched for everyone person who can inspect a little of JavaScript.

Comment: @JuanAndres who in this scenario are you worried about doing this?

Comment: well, let me tell you a little more about what I wanna do,

I want to create a JS Sdk to sell things for my customers where I will have many companies where each company belongs to X "Client_id" and "Secret_key"

so when any "customer" want to sell something to "Company 1" the Users will be able to see the CLIENT_ID and SECRET_KEY according to the Comapany thay wanna buy the product..

So, that is my doubt

Comment: It's hard to fully understand your use-case, i would have to ask a lot more questions. But if a user has to manually enter a secret in their browser, and only their own browser is calling your API then your secret gives you as much protection as any password.

Comment: If the intention is that users of your API build their own apps, and those apps will be used by other random users on the internet, then this sounds like a security problem and this is not the approach you should be taking.

Comment: well, that is the question, because those apps will be used by random users, but Is there a way to check if the Oauth authentication provides from any domain, lets say:

- Only the domain "mydomain.com" is able to do the auth with client_credentials

?

Comment: @JuanAndres if you have 3 parties (you, your API clients and their users) then the correct flow is `authorization_code`, not `client_credentials`